# How to add two collection view cell by indexPath?

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewcell

Lets say we got 4 collection view cells like this :

[image: What I have]

If I am going to replace two collection view cell at cell 3 and cell 4 position like this :

[image: What I want]

As you can see,cell 3 and cell 4 goes down and new cell 1 and cell 2 replace their position.

Is there any way that I can do that at UICollectionView?

I am beginner at using `UICollectionView` because all my app development is full of tableview usage.So,I want to learn more.

Any Code help is appreciated.GitHub repo of example will be more appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: May be you can update your array like that then update collection view.

Comment: Update the dataSource of your UICollectionView.

Comment: Any code help if u don't mind?I mean if you have some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [HERE](https://github.com/bpascazio/CollectionViewExample) I took a sample project for collection view and I did some modification in it as per your requirement.

And below is the complete code for that where I am updating collection array when user press a button on view.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource, CustomCollectionViewCellDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var overlayView: UIView!

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    @IBOutlet weak var overlayLabel: UILabel!

    var purchaseCount:Float = 0.0

    //Your collection view data source at start.
    var cellArray = ["Cell 1", "Cell 2", "Cell 3", "Cell 4"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 50, left: 25, bottom: 50, right: 25)
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
        collectionView!.collectionViewLayout = layout
        collectionView!.dataSource = self
        collectionView!.delegate = self
        collectionView!.registerClass(CollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell")
        collectionView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return cellArray.count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        cell.textLabel?.text = cellArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "circle")
        cell.imageViewStar?.image = UIImage(named: "star")
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }

    //action when user press button into view
    @IBAction func addNewCell(sender: AnyObject) {

        //Insert an element into your collection array.
        cellArray.insert("New Cell 1", atIndex: 2)
        cellArray.insert("New Cell 2", atIndex: 3)

        //reload your collection view.
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }

    // MARK: CustomCollectionViewCellDelegate

    func starImageHit(price:Float) {
        print("star image hit in view controller")
        self.purchaseCount = self.purchaseCount + price
        self.overlayView.hidden = false
        self.overlayView.alpha = 1.0
        self.overlayLabel.text = "\(self.purchaseCount)"
       UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.overlayView.alpha = 0.0
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

And you will get result:

[image]

And [HERE](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=73391187488527661457) is sample project for you.

Comment: Thanks,I got the answer now and I am working on with navigation which was concerned with didSelectItemAtIndexPath.If I need a help,I will reply you.Thanks for giving some time to beginner like me.Really appreciated it.

Comment: Happy to help you.. :)